# Combine single .nii files into one 4D .nii file

Tags: python, nilearn

Is there any possibility to combine many single 3D .nii files into one 4D .nii file using tools in Python?

Simply example via Nilearn doesn't work:

```
Reference shape:
(64, 64, 35)
Image shape:
(64, 64, 35, 1)
```